# How would I determine whether a state lost or grew in population?

Tags: java, arrays, list, delimiter

I am using delimiters to read two different files, one that is comma separated and the other that is tab separated. I put these files into two array lists. Now I'd like to compare them by saying which states lost population (should only be Michigan I believe) and which ones gained.

```
package delim;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File fi = new File("2010census.txt");
        File fil = new File("2000census.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fi).useDelimiter("[|,|\n|\r]+");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(fil).useDelimiter("[\t|\n|\r]+");
        String stateName;
        int numb;
        ArrayList<Integer> arrL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrL2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //while loop to read 2000 census
        while (kb.hasNext()) {
            stateName = kb.next();
            numb = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println(stateName + " " + numb);
            arrL.add(numb);
        }
        //while loop to read 2010 census
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            stateName = sc.next();
            numb = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(stateName + " " + numb);
            arrL2.add(numb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get a csv reader like the one from Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a HashMap to link state to value. You'd declare the hashmaps before reading the csv's and the map.put would be within the loops while reading in your csv's

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm2000 = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
HashMap<String,Integer> hm2010 = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 

// Add to hashmap
map.put("<state>", population);
```

Then iterate over either one by keys, compare to the other hashmap

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Book> entry:hm2000.entrySet()){    
    int key=entry.getKey();  
    // Compare the value from the other hashmap, store it in an array / 
    // other hashmap for reporting at the end
    ...
}
```

Now you can do what you want with the data.

Note: this isn't he most elegant way to do this but it should be a good start for you.